# Randomize nth-of-type?

Tags: jquery

```
alert(Math.floor(Math.random()*71+1));
```

returns a number between 1 and 71, including them.

```
alert($(".program > div:nth-of-type(5)".text())
```

returns a text in 5th div of corresponding parent. Yet

```
alert($(".program > div:nth-of-type(Math.floor(Math.random()*71+1))").text());
```

doesn't work at all. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, what you want is:

```
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 71 + 1)
$(".program > div:nth-of-type(" + rnd + ")").text()
```

The first parameter of `$()` is a selector, just a string. jQuery parses it, but does not evaluate any JS expressions, which are not supposed to be inside.

Comment: Shouldn't `val` be `var`? Or am I missing out on something?

Comment: @BramVanroy Tnx, fixed to `var` (mixed up with another language :-)).